# polymorphic downcasting for derived classes with additional members

Tags: c++

Consider a class `Base` with virtual functions and a class `Derived` from Base implementing the virtual functions, but with few additional private members.
Can we safely downcast the `Base*` pointer to `Derived*` pointer?

```
Base* base = new Derived();

Derived* derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base); // Is this valid?
```

What if derived class contains an additional private member int _derivedNum apart from implementation of virtual functions in the base class? Can I still use derived->_derivedNum to access the private member of the derived class after downcasting the base class pointer?

Comment: It should be `dynamic_cast< Derived * >`.

Comment: Thanks just corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With one minor proviso, yes, that's exactly what `dynamic_cast` is built for.

The proviso is that your cast needs to be to `pointer to Derived` instead of just `Derived`:

```
Derived* derived = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(base);
```

But the basic point of `dynamic_cast` is that it first checks that the pointee object is really of the derived type, and then returns a pointer to it, or returns a null pointer if the pointee object isn't actually of (or derived from) the requested target type.

Also note that for it to work, the base class needs to contain at least one virtual function (though if it doesn't contain any virtual functions, it's *probably* not intended to be used as a base class anyway. There are exceptions to that (e.g., `std::iterator`) but they are exceptions, not the general rule.

Comment: The base class destructor should be virtual anyway if he's inheriting from it.

Comment: Also note that although standard does not mention RTTI in this case, in general, it is necessary that RTTI is enabled for `dynamic_cast` to function properly. Of course, it depends on a particular compiler, but, for instance, MSVC will throw `__non_rtti_object` if RTTI is disabled and the `dynamic_cast` cannot be performed without a runtime check.

Comment: What if there is an additional member int _derivedNum only in the derived class not just implementations of virtual functions. Can I use derived->_derivedNum to access the private member of the derived class after downcasting the base class pointer?

Comment: @vkaul11: After a successful down-cast, you have a `derived *`, so you get full access to the derived object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you certainly can.  The cast is a runtime function, based on runtime type identification.  If it fails, it returns a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can , safely downcast the Base* pointer to Derived* pointer.

```
Base* base = new Derived();   
Derived* derived;

//Null is returned, if the cast is not safe

if( (derived = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(base))  != NULL)
{
//cast ok, can call methods of derived class
}
```